# Generate the code for Blazor services based on controllers?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm writing a Blazor webassembly application, and I would like to rationalize the code in the client.

In the server part, there are controllers. In the client part, there are services calling for the controllers. Usually, one service calls only one controller. I'm not comfortable with the code of the client services, as IMO it is redundant with the code of the server controller. See example below.

**Server controller sample**

```
[Route("api/[controller]/{Lodge}/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class CatalogController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public CatalogController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public Item[] GetAllItems(string Lodge)
    {
        Lodge = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Lodge);
        return new Item[]
        {
            // Get the data from a database
            new Item() { Name = string.Format("{0} 1", Lodge) },
            new Item() { Name = string.Format("{0} 2", Lodge) },
            new Item() { Name = string.Format("{0} 3", Lodge) }
        };
    }

}
```

**Client service sample**

```
public interface ICatalogService
{

    Task<Item[]> AllItems(string Lodge);

}

public class CatalogService : ICatalogService
{

    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CatalogService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<Item[]> AllItems(string Lodge)
    {
        return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Item[]>(string.Format("api/catalog/{0}/getallitems", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Lodge)));
    }

}
```

I am not happy with the the code for method `AllItems` in the service because

1. Redundant with the definition of the controller. The return type and the parameters could be infered based on controller definition.
2. Error prone as I have to build the URL for the controller "by-hand". But it is already defined in the controller route.
3. Error prone again, as I use a generic method `GetFromJsonAsync`, so I guess there is a deserialize operation somewhere in it. If there is a mismatch between controller return type and service call, I'd prefer a compile error instead of a runtime error.

Actually, I would be very happy NOT writing the code for the service, as it seems all the needed info are already present in the controller definition. Is there any coding scheme, or framework, or code-generator tool to do that for me and solve the all 3 issues above ?

Comment: I resorted to writing a templated Controller<TEntity,Tkey> : ControllerBase and a templated DataGrid<TEntity> : ComponentBase. This solved a lot of the issues you refer too. I can see no reason why you could not do the same for a service. My templated controller implements  [EnableQuery()] to further reduce coding in the client.

Comment: IMO a [generic controller](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/04/generic-and-dynamically-generated-controllers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) with [community ODATA](https://github.com/IharYakimush/comminity-data-odata-linq) solve your issue. Sample [there](https://github.com/Aguafrommars/TheIdServer/blob/master/src/IdentityServer/Aguacongas.IdentityServer.Admin/GenericApiController.cs).

Comment: @aguafrommars Your "generic" controller has the same issue as mine had, the type of the key is unknown for the controller method signatures. That's why is had to add TKey. [EnableQuery] enables Odata queries.

Comment: @BrianParker implementation detail ;-) but the solution is the same.

Comment: @aguafrommars Yeah sorry was not bagging your implementation. Just pointing out how I handled the signatures. Obviously your solution met your needs.

Comment: @BrianParker If I understand well the generic controller you are suggesting, it would work fine for basic CRUD operations. But what if I have "complex" API operations, beyond simple get/update/delete ? I mean every service will have different operations, how to fit that into a generic controller ?

Comment: @SilvèreLHERMITE Like any class methods can be overwritten. Business logic should not be in the controller.